# How to import YYYY/MM and YYYY/MM/DD to a same column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I want to import some data from a text file to a `PostgreSQL` table. when I create the table I have a column with a data type of `DATE`. when I want to import the data, it gives this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "2009/11"

Some of my data for that column has the format of `YYYY/MM/DD` and some of them has the format of `YYYY/MM`. Now my question is how can I import these data?

Comment: if the day is not required I would just add a /01 to the YYYY/MM input.

Comment: @Jaxedin I import the data with this command: \copy Papers FROM 'Papers.txt'; How can I add just a /01 to the data while importing?

Comment: oh. That's an important step... Is a one time operation or you have to import that file more than once? Have you access to the process that outpus Papers.txt?

Comment: @Jaxedin I just have the file, I do not have access to the program which output this file. And this is a only one-time operation.

Comment: Ah ok. I dont't know much about postgreSQL (I'm mssql guy). If I were you I would make a script to process that file and add the missing /01 (if day is not important) or make that column (or create a new one and then deleted it) text type, and add the day using a SQL Query.

Comment: I meant, create another column, fix the data and copy it over or change DATE to TEXT value, fix it and then change it back to DATE type

Comment: @Jaxedin I guess if I want to convert TEXT to DATE for "2009/11" it will give the same error!

Comment: yup. But you can fix the data using SQL queries before change it back to DATE format. Something like update table set datecol = datecol + "/01" where len(datecol) = 7... That in postgressql syntax

Comment: @Jaxedin you may want to write these comments as an answer to this question, and I will approve your answer!

Comment: `select to_date('2009/11','yyyy/mm/dd'), to_date('2009/11/12','yyyy/mm/dd');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record. I don't use PostgresSQL myself so I don't know if there is a native tool or way of doing this.

Since it's a one time operation, I would change the datatype of the column from DATE to TEXT, or create a new temp TEXT column.

Import the txt file on that table and execute a query to add the missing day (since it's not important but required by the DATE format)

```
UPDATE table SET dateColumn = dateColumn + '/01' WHERE len(dateColumn) = 7;
```

Please write that in a valid PostgresSQL syntax. You should update the column value and add it '/01' when its length is 7 (YYYY/MM).

Afterwards, copy the value from the temp column to the DATE column or change the datatype back to DATE. Whatever path you choose before.

Merry Xmas!

Comment: eww, the answer below by Dudu is much better.

Answer (score 2):

```
select to_date(dateColumn,'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

---

```
select to_date('2009/11/07','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

> 2009-11-07

```
select to_date('2009/11','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

> 2009-11-01

```
select to_date('2009','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

> 2009-01-01

Comment: There solution is very simple in this case

Comment: I want to import data, and it gives error while importing! how select command can help?

Comment: If you  are doing an update as in the other answer this is the cleanest way to do it

Comment: I thought you are giving the whole solution, so you agree to convert the DATE to TEXT and import data and then convert back?

Comment: You don't have dates in a text file. You are loading it in a text and then convert it to dates. I'm also  looking for a more straightforward way.